# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when using ROWN_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting the following error on a small piece of code and cant resolve it.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
SELECT * 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT fieldb, description, mpaid, entry_date, ROWN_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mpaid ORDER BY entry_date desc) AS rn
     FROM mydatatable 
     WHERE mpaid IN ('1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '5555', '6666')) AS gg
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: `AS gg` will not work in Oracle. Oracle doesn't support `AS` for table aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical typo , row_number and not rown_number()

```
SELECT * 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT fieldb, description, mpaid, entry_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mpaid ORDER BY entry_date desc) AS rn
     FROM mydatatable 
     WHERE mpaid IN ('1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '5555', '6666')) gg
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Also, in oracle there is RANK() function which is used for this, not sure if its better or not(performance wise) but rank() deals with ties and gives them the same rank (if thats what you need:)

```
SELECT * 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT fieldb, description, mpaid, entry_date, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mpaid ORDER BY entry_date desc) AS rn
     FROM mydatatable 
     WHERE mpaid IN ('1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '5555', '6666')) gg
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Also as aleksej pointed , as is a type too .

Comment: Ah man, missed the typo! lemme retry

Comment: Fixed with your answer and Aleksej's, also ROW_NUMBER() worked and RANK() didnt give me the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You have two typos: `ROWN_NUMBER` and the `AS` before `gg`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT fieldb, description, mpaid, entry_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mpaid ORDER BY entry_date desc) AS rn
     FROM mydatatable 
     WHERE mpaid IN ('1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '5555', '6666'))  gg
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: typo's killin' me! Yeh working now!